# Return multiple data elements

Tags: xquery

Using Xquery, how can I search the file below (consisting of many items), for all items with 'XC' in the part-number (there are many), then for matches return all 3 of the interesting data elements (part-number, part-name, and name)?  The return is the main problem--my attempts result in every permutation of the interesting data elements.  Thank you!

```
    
<catalog>
   <item>
     <description>
    <partref>
       <part-id>
        <part-number>XC51222</part-number>
       </part-id>
    </partref>
    <part-name>DSP, Network Vectoring<part-name>
    <vendors>
       <vendor1>
        <pay-to>
           <name>JCOF Industries</name>
        </pay-to>
       </vendor1>
    </vendors>
      </description>
   </item>
   <item>
   </item>
[many items…]
</catalog>
```

Comment: What does your XPath look like so far?

Comment: Right now I am skipping the search bit and just trying to get the return right. So I have a tiny subset of the catalog-- just three items. I want the following return:

Comment: I want the following return:  (part-number1, name1, part-number2, name2, part-number3, name3) in csv.  I know this will look convoluted, so keep in mind I'm a rookie... let $sep := ','
let $pn:= /catalog/item/description/partref/part-id/part-number
for $pn in /catalog/item/description/partref/part-id/part-number
let $name := /catalog/item/vendors/vendor1/name
for $name in /catalog/item/vendors/vendor1/name
return string-join(($pn,$name),$sep)
I have tried every combo of for loop; this is just the latest attempt.

Comment: The output I get is every combination of pn and name-- pn1,name1,pn1,name2,pn1,name3,pn2,name1,pn2,name2,etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $sep := ','
for $x in catalog/item
where fn:matches($x/description/partref/part-id/part-number, 'XC')
return fn:string-join( ($x/description/partref/part-id/part-number/text(), $x/description/part-name/text(), $x/description/vendors/vendor1/pay-to/name/text()), $sep)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!  How can I cause the $sep to appear not only between elements, but between returns too?  So instead of x1,y1,z1x2,y2,z2 I will get x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2?

Comment: I got it.  concat ($sep, string-join((blah, blah),$sep)).